# How to disable mobile meta tag on only one page?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

This works fine for every page but one

```
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I am in a rails project and I am sending one page to a client that needs to be formated much differently. Is there a way to disable this meta tag on only one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probable have this in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

There's two ways:

1) You can create as many of those as you want, and then in your controller [specify which one to use](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html):

```
render layout: 'special_client'
```

2) You add a condition in your layout:

```
<% unless @hide_viewport %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<% end %>
```

And in your controller you set

```
def special_client_method
  ...
  @hide_viewport = true
end
```